# how to specify the first cell with data in it inside an if statement in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I keep a running avg of kids grades in Excel over a 2 week period. The way i have the code now

```
AVERAGE(OFFSET('1'!E4,COUNTA('1'!D:D)-29,):OFFSET('1'!E4,COUNTA('1'!D:D),))
```

it returns an error if i don't have 2 weeks of data. I found a way around this by doing this

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(OFFSET('1'!E4,COUNTA('1'!D:D)-29,):OFFSET('1'!E4,COUNTA('1'!D:D),)),IFERROR(AVERAGE(OFFSET('1'!E4,COUNTA('1'!D:D)-28,):OFFSET('1'!E4,COUNTA('1'!D:D),)),IFERROR(AVERAGE(OFFSET('1'!E4,COUNTA('1'!D:D)-27,....
```

Im Sure there is a better way to do this any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please describe briefly your table setup and how the two-week period is determined?

Comment: @user1975188 Screen will rock as well)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments - it's difficult to give a definitive answer without some more knowledge - it's not easy to tell, for instance, where the numeric data starts (E4 or E5)?

Firstly you can simplify your original formula which appears to AVERAGE the last 30 rows of data (not sure how 30 rows equates to 2 weeks of data) - you can do that with just:

`=AVERAGE(OFFSET('1'!E4,COUNTA('1'!D:D)-29,0,30))`

Now I assume the error comes about when COUNTA('1'!D:D) is < 29 so you can simply add an If function which AVERAGES all the data if that function returns a number < 29, i.e.

`=IF(COUNTA('1'!D:D)<29,AVERAGE('1'!E4:E33),AVERAGE(OFFSET('1'!E4,COUNTA('1'!D:D)-29,0,30)))`

That formula may need some small adjustments to cater for the specifics of your layout but the general approach is valid